# inner class extending

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

In java, say I have the following class:

```
public class A{
  protected class B{
  }
}
```

can I extend the inner class by doing the following?

```
public class C extends A{
  protected class D extends B{
  }
}
```

What I want to do is that I have the class C above and I need to change something in A's inner class so I was thinking that I need to extend the inner class to do so but I wasn't sure how exactly to do that.

Comment: Yes you can extend the inner class like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this page](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/nestedclasses.html#EXTENDING), you have the right way figured out to extend inner classes. A few tips about it can be found [here](http://java.sys-con.com/node/35776), in the middle of the article (search for "extend").

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't work (I don't think it will), the following should:

```
public class C extends A{
  protected class D extends A.B{
  }
}
```

Well, it will, but what if you have another class named `B` outside of `A`?

Edit: nope, it makes no difference. Even if there is another class named `B`, it will still take `A.B`. So your syntax is correct.

Comment: It wouldn't work if `D` was `static`, but it's not, so it does.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to do that but don't expect your C class to use D class instead of A's inner B class automatically.

Comment: This is the truly crucial aspect with inheritance of outer/inner class data structures. Is there any known pattern to deal with this problem (generics etc.)?

Comment: I'd say inject the actual instance of B (B or D in this case) you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

> Each inner class can independently inherit from an implementation.
>   Thus, the inner class is not limited by whether the outer class is
>   already inheriting from an implementation.

--- *Thinking In Java*